# php preg_replace help iframe src

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have created a function which will set height, width and wmode=transparent for youtube embed codes. Now youtube is returning iframe code. So, I need to append "?wmode=transparent"  at the end of youtube src.

For eg.
Original code :

> <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="420" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aXNUL1-urg8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

I want it to be replaced with :

> <iframe title="YouTube video player" width=" **mywidth**" height=" **myheight**" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aXNUL1-urg8 **?wmode=transparent**" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

Replacing height and width is working, but replacing src does not work.

I am using below regex

$patterns[] = '/src="http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/[a-zA-Z0-9._-]"/';
$replacements[] = 'src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/${1}?wmode=transparent"';

Below is my function.

> function SetHeightWidthVideo($markup,$w='200',$h='120')
>   {
>         //to make it wmode = transparent
>
> ```
>   $markup = str_replace('<embed ','<embed wmode="transparent" ',$markup);
>   //$w = '200';
>   //$h = '120';
>
>   $patterns = array();
>   $replacements = array();
>   if( !empty($w) )
>   {
>       $patterns[] = '/width="([0-9]+)"/';
>       $patterns[] = '/width:([0-9]+)/';
>
>       $replacements[] = 'width="'.$w.'"';
>       $replacements[] = 'width:'.$w;
>   }
>
>   if( !empty($h) )
>   {
>       $patterns[] = '/height="([0-9]+)"/';
>       $patterns[] = '/height:([0-9]+)/';
>
>       $replacements[] = 'height="'.$h.'"';
>       $replacements[] = 'height:'.$h;
>   }
>
>
>
>   $patterns[] = '/src="http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/[a-zA-Z0-9._-]"/';
>   $replacements[] = 'src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/${1}?wmode=transparent"';
>
>   return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $markup);
> ```
>
> }

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a `+` on the end of your `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]` expression. Right now it is only able to match one char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$patterns[] = '/src="(.*?)"/';
$replacements[] = 'src="${1}?wmode=transparent"';

return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $markup);
```

Answer (score 2):

copy, paste, run:

```
function setHeightWidthSrc($s, $width, $height)
{
  return preg_replace(
    '@^<iframe\s*title="(.*)"\s*width="(.*)"\s*height="(.*)"\s*src="(.*?)"\s*(.*?)</iframe>$@s',
    '<iframe title="\1" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '" src="\4?wmode=transparent" \5</iframe>',
    $s
  );
}

$original = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" 
  width="420" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aXNUL1-urg8" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
';
print "$original\n";
print setHeightWidthSrc($original, 100, 100) . "\n";
```