# How to change the iframe width and height in PHP

Tags: php

Can any body tell how to change the width & height of iframe in php.
in database i am saving below format.while i am displaying i want to fixed size.

this is the iframe content

```
<iframe width="400" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c7ct6pNOvEE?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

`Here width & height changes dynamically` based on site.then how to convert the width to 500 & height to 350 in php

Thanks in advance

Comment: PHP runs server-side, so you can't change the size real-time on the client-side. You need Javascript for that.

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with dynamic changes to the markup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414666/php-preg-replace-help-iframe-src?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just use CSS

```
html, body, iframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

Edit: Next time you should define your question **PROPERLY** and add a proper descriotion before you post it.

Anyway, since you have the sizes in the database you can simply use echo's to change the size. First you need to get the width and height from the database, then echo it in your HTML.

```php
<?php
$iframe = html_entity_decode($post['url']);
$newWidth = 610;
$newHeight = 450;
?>

<iframe
    src="<?php echo $iframe; ?>"
    height="<?php echo $newHeight; ?>"
    width="<?php echo $newWidth; ?>"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

---

Edit v12351524274573523

```
$iframe = '<iframe width="400" height="225" src="youtube.com/embed/c7ct6pNOvEE?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$src = html_entity_decode($post['url']);
$height = 450;
$width = 610;

// add autoplay
$src = $src . (strstr($src, '?') ? '&': '?') . 'autoplay=1';

$iframe = preg_replace('/src="(.*?)"/i', 'src="' . $src .'"', $iframe);
$iframe = preg_replace('/height="(.*?)"/i', 'height="' . $height .'"', $iframe);
$iframe = preg_replace('/width="(.*?)"/i', 'width="' . $width .'"', $iframe);
```

Comment: this is my sample code 
getting from database
$iframe = html_entity_decode($post['url']);

$newWidth = 610;
$newHeight = 450;
now i want to the new width & height assign to the i frame

Comment: but in DB i am storing like this 
<iframe width="400" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c7ct6pNOvEE?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: how to change the autopay=1 in iframe src.if it is not exist then add it to the src Using PHP.

this is the sample code

<iframe width="610" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.viddler.com/embed/6d067eb/?f=1&autoplay=0&player=full&loop=false&nologo=false&hd=false">