# Add "wmode" parameter to src of an iframe with PHP

Tags: php, regex, iframe, wmode

I have had some problems with the z-index of a FLASH- and an overlaying DIV-element.

I've used this jQuery/Javascript solution, which adds the "wmode=transparent" parameter to the "src" of every (YouTube & Vimeo) iframe, to solve the z-index issues (e.g. flickering, etc).

```
...

content.find('iframe').each(function() {

   var iframe_source = $(this).attr('src');
   var iframe_wmode = "wmode=transparent";

   if ( iframe_source.indexOf('?') != -1 )
   {
       iframe_source = iframe_source.split('?');
       $(this).attr('src',iframe_source[0]+'?'+iframe_wmode+'&'+iframe_source[1]);
   }
   else
   {
       $(this).attr('src',iframe_source+'?'+iframe_wmode);
   }

});

...
```

Now I need this solution in **PHP**, because I still have some z-index-flickering (during the rendering of the DOM) until the jQuery/Javascript solution corrects this problem *( on $(window).load(function(){} ...  $(document).ready(function(){} is not possible for me)*.

My PHP content looks like this for example ...

```
...

$content = '
foo bar foo bar
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GASFa7rkLtM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
foo bar foo bar
<iframe width="100" height="100" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GASFa7rkLtM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
foo bar foo bar
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/GASFa7rkLtM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
foo bar foo bar
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/57959739?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
foo bar foo bar';

...
```

... and shoud look like this after some preg_match/regex-magic ;)

```
...

$content = '
foo bar foo bar
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GASFa7rkLtM?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
foo bar foo bar
<iframe width="100" height="100" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GASFa7rkLtM?rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
foo bar foo bar
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/GASFa7rkLtM?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
foo bar foo bar
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/57959739?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&wmode=transparent" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
foo bar foo bar';

...
```

Many thanks in advance!

Best Mike =)

PS:
My idea is to solve the z-index problem via PHP in advance (server-side, not client-side).

PPS:
FYI - I get the "content" string with HTML-content/-tags out of a MySQL-DB, and I want to modify these string, instead of modifieng the DOM via jQuery/Javascript.

---

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

Buliding on the regex-solution from "One Trick Pony" worked for me. I edited the first and add a second "preg_replace". The first one adds "?wmode=transparent" to the end of each iframe-src and the second replaces the "?" with "&" if exists twice in the url.

```
$content = preg_replace('#\<iframe(.*?)\ssrc\=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)\>#i',
                        '<iframe$1 src="$2?wmode=transparent"$3>', $content);

$content = preg_replace('#\<iframe(.*?)\ssrc\=\"(.*?)\?(.*?)\?(.*?)\"(.*?)\>#i',
                        '<iframe$1 src="$2?$3&$4"$5>', $content);
```

Not a beautiful solution, but it worked perfect for my purpose.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Unless that HTML structure stays the same, there's no way you can have reliable replacements with regex here. Use a xml parser, get the `src` attribute of iframes and append your query string to it.

Comment: Ideally I would need a better solution like this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414666/php-preg-replace-help-iframe-src ), which takes care of YouTube- and Vimeo-iframes and their existing parameters (e.g. ?rel=0, ?autoplay=1) in the url of the src. Is that possible via regex?

Comment: Possible: maybe. Easy? no. Maintainable? No. Robust? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($content);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $ifr){

  // use parse_url here, change query and rebuild it if you want to be 100% sure 
  $src = rtrim($ifr->getAttribute('src'), '&') . '&wmode=transparent';

  $ifr->setAttribute('src', $src);
}

$content = $dom->saveHtml();
```

---

A basic try with regular expressions using greedy matches:

```
$content = preg_replace('#\<iframe(.*?)\ssrc\=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)\>#i', 
                        '<iframe$1 src="$2&wmode=transparent"$3>',  $content);
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me! No z-index problems and no clientside DOM manipulations anymore. ... Many thanks for the quick answer, the great solution(s) and the awesome regex-magic! =) ... (Maybe I will use the safer solution via DomDocument and "src"-rebuild later after some testing.) THX